# Oracle stored procedure to generate random code

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

We are running a system to provide traceablity service to small householders in Vietnam. The system run on Oracle 12i DB and it has a stored procedure to generate random code to make QR code space for the system as below:

```
PROCEDURE GENCODE 
(
  PI_NUM_CODE IN NUMBER 
) AS 
ind number;
code_gen varchar2(10);
BEGIN
  for ind in 1..PI_NUM_CODE loop
      begin
        code_gen := dbms_random.string('X', 10);
        insert into tb_code_gen(s_code) values(code_gen);
        exception when others then
          dbms_output.put_line(code_gen);
      end;
    end loop;
END GENCODE;
```

Can you please be so kind to explain the `IN NUMBER` statement for me with thanks. I am trying to help the partners to fix this code to make the system run.

Can you please explain and help me to understand the statement with thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pi_num_code` is number of rows (QR codes, as you said) you want to generate when procedure is executed. That's - in procedure - number of times `FOR` loop runs.

Here's an example.

Target table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE tb_code_gen
  2  (
  3     s_code   VARCHAR2 (20)
  4  );

Table created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE gencode (pi_num_code IN NUMBER)
  2  AS
  3     ind       NUMBER;
  4     code_gen  VARCHAR2 (10);
  5  BEGIN
  6     FOR ind IN 1 .. pi_num_code       --> "run code within the loop PI_NUM_CODE number of times"
  7     LOOP
  8        BEGIN
  9           code_gen := DBMS_RANDOM.string ('X', 10);
 10
 11           INSERT INTO tb_code_gen (s_code)
 12                VALUES (code_gen);
 13        EXCEPTION
 14           WHEN OTHERS
 15           THEN
 16              DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (code_gen);
 17        END;
 18     END LOOP;
 19  END gencode;
 20  /

Procedure created.
```

Enable output (otherwise you wouldn't see if something is displayed with `dbms_output.put_line` in exception handling section):

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
```

Let's generate 3 codes:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2     gencode (pi_num_code => 3);
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Here they are:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM tb_code_gen;

S_CODE
--------------------
G31O4H7M90
SXTESE3HYJ
PPCL6PAU17

SQL>
```

---

On the other hand, you don't need a loop (nor a procedure) - insert can do that:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO tb_code_gen (s_code)
  2         SELECT DBMS_RANDOM.string ('X', 10)
  3           FROM DUAL
  4     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;      --> this "3" is value you passed to procedure

3 rows created.                     --> another 3 rows created

SQL> SELECT * FROM tb_code_gen;

S_CODE
--------------------
G31O4H7M90
SXTESE3HYJ
PPCL6PAU17
GDEU7I42PZ
JGLGY11URW
EN2T4NTCI6

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please be so kind to explain the `IN NUMBER` statement for me

This is in the [Oracle `CREATE PROCEDURE` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/CREATE-PROCEDURE-statement.html#GUID-5F84DB47-B5BE-4292-848F-756BF365EC54__BABJEGID):

```sql
PROCEDURE GENCODE 
(
  PI_NUM_CODE IN NUMBER 
) AS
```

- `PROCEDURE` states that you are defining a procedure (presumably as part of a `PACKAGE` as you do not include the `CREATE` keyword beforehand that is used for creating a stand-alone procedure).
- `GENCODE` is the identifier (name) of the procedure.
- `(` starts the parameter declararion.
- `PI_NUM_CODE` is the identifier (name) of the procedure's first parameter (or argument).
- `IN` states that the parameter will be used to input data into the procedure.
- `NUMBER` is the data type of the parameter.
- `)` ends the parameter declaration.
- `AS` ends the procedure's signature and starts the body of the procedure.

Comment: thanks for your explanation! it would be pity that I will have to run into code to change the parameter!

Comment: @ĐặngĐìnhNgọc If you want to change the parameter's data type or direction then you would have to change the code but if you want to change the value of the parameter then you do not need to change the code just pass a different value when you call the procedure. I.e. `GENCODE(1)` or `GENCODE(42)`.

Comment: Yes @MT0, the parameter was set on the code (java) so I have to ask the developer to fix this for us!

Answer (score 0):

PI_NUM_CODE IN NUMBER ----> is input parameter for procedure GENCODE.
while calling the procedure you need to passe it.

for e.g.

begin
GENCODE(5);--here we have passed 5 as parameter value.so accordingly your
loop will execute 5 time as mentioned in you procedure logic.
end;